# issue with htaccess ,url rewrite and query string

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I wanted to have a URL like this www.mydomain.com/19127axbj1 and basically when this is executed what is being called is www.mydomain.com/parser.php?id=19127axbj1. How can I do this? Is this even possible? I see a lot of sites doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following rewrite rule in a .htaccess file at web root:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ parser.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: when you mean web root, so say my parser.php is located at /var/www/mysite, I put the .htaccess at mysite?

Comment: when I try to do I get www.mydomain.com/parser.php?id=NLYoLzVUN4 it says "The requested URL /NLYoLzVUN4 was not found on this server"

Comment: Are you sure that AllowOverride is enabled?

Comment: how do I do AllowOverride on directory?

Comment: In the apache/httpd config file you need to specify `AllowOverride All` for the appropriate Directory or VirtualHost. What is your server's system?

Comment: seems that my apache2/httpd config file is empty

Comment: Sorry I meant that it is the base configuration file for Apache, which is sometimes named httpd.conf. If I knew your server's system I could tell you where it might be. In Ubuntu server it is located at:  /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default . In RHEL it is located at /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf .

Comment: I had this in my conf <Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Files>

Comment: I would try setting `AllowOverride All` close to where things are set for your site. (So that this directive only applies to your site.)

Comment: ok, now I have  <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
but still it won't do it, this is inside the vhost of the site

Comment: Have you restarted Apache since saving your changes?

Comment: okay I got it to work now, however when I navigate to www.site.com it also rewrites this URL to the parser.php.. I want to exclude this so it's not rewritten

Comment: Not sure I understand your last comment. Is it a different domain (or ServerAlias) that is using the same doc/web root? www.site.com versus www.mydomain.com?